# Why React ref element.current returns null in React component using useRef hook?

Tags: reactjs, ref, use-ref

I need to query a DOM element and using `useRef` hook:

```
const Overlay = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myRef.current);
  }, [myRef]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog fullScreen open={open}>
        <DialogContent id="dialog" ref={myRef}>
          <header>
           // Header
          </header>
          {children}
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Overlay;
```

If I inspect the console it returns `null`.

What do I have to do to query the DOM element using `useRef`?

Comment: [Forwaring Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: @Yousaf thanks. But how do I have to use `React.forwardRef` in my case (with the Material UI Dialog or DialogContent?

Comment: I would expect `MaterialUI` to forward the ref to the underlying native DOM element. Check their docs to see if they allow the users the access the underlying DOM element.

Comment: @Yousaf you mean without `forwardRef`? Just use the `ref` prop like in my example? According to [the docs](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog-content/), the `ref` is forwarded to the root element. But then the question is, why it's returning `null` now?

Comment: _"you mean without forwardRef? Just use the ref prop like in my example?"_ - yes. If the component forwards the ref to the native DOM element, then your code should work. Can you create a minimal, reproducible demo and share the link?

Comment: @Yousaf thanks, here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-glade-xucbp) to the sandbox. If you inspect console you see the ref returns null

Comment: I have seen the demo you created - i only get null after the first page load; after that, native DOM element gets logged on the console. Can i ask why you need `ref` for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: _" I think useRef isn't going to work with Material UI in my case. What do you think?"_ - i have never worked with MaterialUI, that's why i am not sure why your original code example doesn't works as it should.

Comment: @Yousaf just found out. I had to add the prop `disablePortal` to the material UI `<Dialog>`. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

So the MUIs `Dialog` component only mounts it's children if `open === true`. I would suggest making your `useEffect` dependant on the `open` state instead of reference.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      console.log(myRef.current);
    } else {
      // myRef.current is null
    }
  }, [open]);
```